# What is the return value of "req.url.indexOf()"?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm very new to node.js and Express so, I'm kind of wondering what is the results/return of `req.url.indexOf()`.

For example, I've seen this code in Express example. 
`if(req.url.indexOf('admin') >= 0)` and `if(req.url.indexOf('/admin') >= 0)` which means "Do you have admin authorization?" I think.

However,as far as I know zero means `false` and positive numbers mean `true`. Maybe the return value of `req.url.indexOf()` is different with what I know. 
Please help me out!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: @BenFortune Hate your Down votes but, Love your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`req.url` is a string containing the currently requested URL *path*.

`indexOf()` is [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), which returns the index of a substring within a string (or -1 if the substring wasn't found).

This code...

```
req.url.indexOf('admin') >= 0
```

...checks if the currently requested URL contains the string *'admin'* (and if so, evaluates to `true`).

Answer (score 1):

indexOf('sth') is a method on String that search the index of the begining of a substring.

If the substring is found, it returns the index >= 0. If not, it returns -1.

```
> var t = "foobar"
undefined
> t.indexOf('ba')
3
> t.indexOf('lol')
-1
```